# new Servlet for each client

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous

```
@WebServlet(value = "/account", asyncSupported = true)
public class AccountServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
     int i = 0;
     private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = 
     Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

     @Override
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
         System.out.println("i="+(++i)); 
     }

     @Override
     public void destroy() {
           executor.shutdown();
     }
}
```

i research for working process of servlet.When i open new tabs in each tab and in new browser.i is increasing.0 1 2 etc. in new tabs and even in new browser.

I think that i must begin from 0 in new tab and new browser.How can we explain why this is so?

Comment: Because your preconceptions aren't correct. Isuggest you do some reding, instead of jumping to conclusions and asking why they're not being fulfilled.

Comment: i am reading book and research what i read step by step

Answer (score 0):

During your entire life cycle of web application only single Object of Servlet is created and for each subsequent request a new thread gets created

> A Java servlet container / web server is typically multithreaded. That
>   means, that multiple requests to the same servlet may be executed at
>   the same time.

So that is why when next time request comes it will not reinitialize the member `i` instead it uses the previous value of `i`